Estimating the conditional entropy of a discrete variable conditioning on continuous variable
I am doing a machine learning project and I am trying to select the best features by computing their mutual information and select the ones with the highest information gain. I was looking at this wikipedia page:
where the following (training ) data set is used as an example of how to compute the information gain:
WEKA weather data
Outlook  Temperature    Humidity    Wind    Play
Sunny    Hot            High        False   No
Sunny    Hot            High        True    No
Overcast Hot            High        False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           High        False   Yes
Rainy    Cool           Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Cool           Normal      True    No
Overcast Cool           Normal      True    Yes
Sunny    Mild           High        False   No
Sunny    Cool           Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           Normal      False   Yes
Sunny    Mild           Normal      False   Yes
Overcast Mild           High        True    Yes
Overcast Hot            Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           High        True    No

where Outlook, Temperature, Humidity, Wing are (categorical) features and Play is the outcome/ target variable. In this case, the author simply estimates the true probability $\pi$ using the count of each observation: $\hat{\pi} := n_k/N$, where $n_k := \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{1}_{x_i=k}$ for each possible outcome $k$. So this is a reasonable thing to do. However, in my project, the features are not categorical, rather they are samples of continuous variables, and my outcome is a binary outcome, so my dataset looks like:
feature1 feature2       feature3    feature4 Outcome
1.2      0.3            -0.2        32       No
3.6      2.3            0.8         11       Yes
9.2      0              -2.7        2        No
3.3      1.5            9.3         92       No

In this case, is there any way to estimate the entropy? Thank you so much in advance.

This is not trivial. Calling $X$ the outcome (discrete) variable, and $Y$ the continuous one, if $X$ is Bernoulli (two values), I would write
$$I(X;Y) = h(Y) - h(Y|X) = h(Y) - (1-p) \cdot h( Y | X=0) - p\cdot h( Y | X=1)$$
where $p = P(X=1)$. We have to estimate $p$ (rather trivial) and the three entropies. For that, there are several methods, see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation and
http://jimbeck.caltech.edu/summerlectures/references/Entropy%20estimation.pdf
Plugging the nearest-neighbour estimator, letting $n=n_1 + n_0$ where $n_0, n_1$ are the number of samples of each kind ($X=0,1$), and $p = n_1/n$, $q=1-p$ we get
$$ \begin{align}
\hat I(X;Y) &= \langle \log d \rangle - p \log p -q \log q -
\left(p \langle \log d_1 \rangle  + q \langle \log  d_0 \rangle\right) \\
&= H_b(p) + \langle \log d \rangle -
\left(p \langle \log d_1 \rangle  + q \langle \log  d_0 \rangle\right)   
\end{align} $$
where $H_b(p)$ is the binary entropy function, $\langle \log d \rangle$ is $\frac1n \sum_u \log d_i$ is the average of the logarithm of the nearest neighbor distances, and the same goes for $\langle \log d_k \rangle$ , restricted over each sample group.
